# invalid syntax in __init__ function

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)
```

However this comes up:
[image]

This code was supposed to print:
[image]

However it resulted in a syntax error.

Comment: If you're working interactively, you need a blank line after the class definition. I see the bottom of the `g`s at the top of that screenshot, meaning there's no blank line there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be something subtly wrong with the way that you typed in the program or something.  Your code works for me ... from the command line on Linux.

```
$ cat /tmp/x.py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)
print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)

$ python3 < /tmp/x.py 
John
36
```

It could be that your actual code is missing a blank line.  (Hint: don't post images ... especially cropped images.)